# Simulate multiple dates between two dates

Tags: r, date, lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
date1<-ymd("2021/01/01")

date2<-ymd("2021/01/31")
```

How can I simulate multiple dates between `"2021-01-01"` and `"2021-01-31"`, for example ten dates like this:

```
[1] "2021-01-21" "2021-01-07" "2021-01-09" "2021-01-18" "2021-01-02" "2021-01-13" "2021-01-24" "2021-01-30" "2021-01-11" "2021-01-25"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seq()`, e.g.

```
library(lubridate)
date1<-ymd("2021/01/01")
date2<-ymd("2021/01/31")
seq(date1, date2, length.out = 10)
>[1] "2021-01-01" "2021-01-04" "2021-01-07" "2021-01-11"
>[5] "2021-01-14" "2021-01-17" "2021-01-21" "2021-01-24"
>[9] "2021-01-27" "2021-01-31"
```

If you want 10 random dates:

```
library(lubridate)
date1<-ymd("2021/01/01")
date2<-ymd("2021/01/31")
dates <- seq(date1, date2, 1)
sample(dates, 10)
>[1] "2021-01-08" "2021-01-03" "2021-01-20" "2021-01-27"
>[5] "2021-01-02" "2021-01-17" "2021-01-19" "2021-01-30"
>[9] "2021-01-11" "2021-01-05"
```